# Celery Worker – remove warn message `[WARNING/MainProcess] celery@localhost ready`

Tags: logging, celery, sentry, raven

When starting Celery Worker it outputs one warn message:
`[2016-06-26 20:30:23,005: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@daniula.local ready`

When setting up Raven client to collect errors and warning to Sentry:

```
from raven.contrib.celery import register_signal, register_logger_signal
import logging 

sentry = Client(config.get('SENTRY_DSN'))
register_logger_signal(sentry, loglevel=logging.WARN)
```

This irrelevant warning is reported to Sentry on every workers restart.

Is there any way to disable it or switch to log.info?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm  running into same thing, and want to be able to use warn log level into my tasks as well.

Comment: Sorry, I gave up on this.

Comment: I think I will too and use only `ERROR` level in my tasks. Seems there are a few more messages like [this one "Restoring %d unacknowledged message(s)"](https://github.com/celery/kombu/blob/84fc45b9a76026c054ab1d31ec3883dd2e56c440/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py#L48) that are printed as a warning as well. Might be even more, idk. So definitely it wouldn't be only one thing to change.

Answer (score 3):

There is an ongoing [issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3462) opened with Celery on this.

You can however add this options to the config and move ANY stdout/stderr to info level in the logger:

```
    'CELERY_REDIRECT_STDOUTS_LEVEL': 'INFO',
```

Comment: It seems that the issue has now been closed and this shouldn't be a problem anymore thanks to this change: https://github.com/celery/celery/commit/c8726b8a48a5c1b07f254cdd2023c00033bdcb6d